# Application crash during Item click of recyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My Application is crashed when I click on ItemView of RecyclerView, There is no error showing in code.
The data are load in toast but not pass to the other class or what don't know, but when I click any Item the appliaction is crash..

This is my Main RecyclerView Class

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity {
     Button addUser;
     RecyclerView mainUserRecyclerView;
     UserAdapter adapter;
     FirebaseDatabase database;
     ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfoArrayList  = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        
        mainUserRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainUserRecyclerView);
        mainUserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        
        addUser = findViewById(R.id.addUserBtn);

        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

       DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("userInfo");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserInfo userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);
                    userInfoArrayList.add(userInfo);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Admin.this,"Failed to get data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        adapter = new UserAdapter(Admin.this,userInfoArrayList);
        mainUserRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

  
      public void setAddUser(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,user_detail.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }

}
```

This is my Adapter Class

```
package com.example.rent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.viewHolder> {
    Context  admin;
   ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfoArrayList;
    public UserAdapter(Admin admin, ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfoArrayList) {

        this.admin = admin;
        this.userInfoArrayList = userInfoArrayList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull  ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(admin).inflate(R.layout.user_list_item,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  UserAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) {
        UserInfo userInfo = userInfoArrayList.get(position);
        holder.user_name.setText(userInfo.getShopName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

           Intent intent = new Intent(admin,Display_User.class);
            //Toast.makeText(admin, ""+userInfo.getOneMonthRent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            intent.putExtra("Name",userInfo.getShopName());
            intent.putExtra("Rent",userInfo.getOneMonthRent());
            intent.putExtra("Complex",userInfo.getComplexName());
            intent.putExtra("PaidRent",userInfo.getPaidAmount());
            intent.putExtra("DMonth",userInfo.getDefaultMonth());
            intent.putExtra("PendingRent",userInfo.getPendingAmount());
            admin.startActivity(intent);

        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userInfoArrayList.size();
    }


   public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView user_name;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull  View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            user_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);

        }
   }
}
```

And The display User class where I have to fetch the data

```
package com.example.rent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Display_User extends AppCompatActivity {


     TextView tvName,tvRent,tvComplex,tvPaidRent,tvDefaultMonth,tvPendingRent;
     String Sname, rent, complex, paidRent, defaultMonth, pendingRent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_user);

        
         Sname = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
         rent = getIntent().getStringExtra("Rent");
         complex = getIntent().getStringExtra("Complex");
         paidRent = getIntent().getStringExtra("PaidRent");
         defaultMonth = getIntent().getStringExtra("DMonth");
         pendingRent = getIntent().getStringExtra("Pending");


        tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvName.setText(Sname);

        tvRent = findViewById(R.id.tvRent);
        tvRent.setText(rent);

        tvComplex = findViewById(R.id.tvComplex);
        tvComplex.setText(complex);

        tvPaidRent = findViewById(R.id.tvPaidRent);
        tvPaidRent.setText(paidRent);

        tvDefaultMonth = findViewById(R.id.tvDefault);
        tvDefaultMonth.setText(defaultMonth);

        tvPendingRent = findViewById(R.id.tvPending);
        tvPendingRent.setText(pendingRent);


    }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: please use callback interface to pass data from UserAdapter class to Display_User activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared the Activity on the manifest file? And the intent ?

Comment: Yes I forgot to add activity on manifest file. Add the activity and now it run fine.